# How to reset Ethernet data usage statistics using python?

Tags: python-3.x, ethernet

How to reset Ethernet data usage statistics using Python? Preferably ctypes or subprocess without rebooting the PC, etc. For example, I want to reset only xray.exe statistics

[image]

Honestly, I’ve already tried all the options, I also tried ChatGPT, but it didn’t want to help me with this. Yes, and I want to reset the statistics without rebooting the PC, etc. Via python using subproccess or ctypes

```
import subprocess
import time

app_name = 'xray.exe'

try:
    pid_command = f'tasklist /fi "imagename eq {app_name}" /fo csv'
    result = subprocess.run(pid_command, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
    pid = result.stdout.split(',')[1]

    reset_command = f'netsh interface ipv4 reset statistics {app_name}'
    try:
        subprocess.run(reset_command, shell=True, check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        pass

    release_command = f'ipconfig /release {app_name}'
    renew_command = f'ipconfig /renew {app_name}'

    subprocess.run(release_command, shell=True, check=True)
    time.sleep(2)
    subprocess.run(renew_command, shell=True, check=True)

finally:
    subprocess.run(f"taskkill /f /pid {pid}", shell=True)
    time.sleep(2)
    subprocess.run(f"start {app_name}", shell=True)
```

Comment: nested try statements...  first time i have seen that.